# how to install ubuntu-server on second HD, from a headless system running ubuntu-server

Tags: server, system-installation, ssh

Two vintage headless/keyboardless systems were running ubuntu-server 16.04LTS (Alpha and Beta);

Access is only via ssh for both machines.

Alpha system was corrupted apparently during an update.

Booting by CD/DVD/UEFI is not an option. USB is turned off at the kernel due to incompatibilities that cause cpu to race at 100%.

Alpha's drive with unbootable system is now mounted as second drive in Beta's system.

All user files have been backed up to Beta's drive.

How to install ubuntu-server on Beta's second (Alpha) hard drive so that the second drive can be reinstalled as primary bootable drive in Alpha system?

kind regards,
Ben

update 2017-01-25:

debootstrap and this url ( https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/i386/apds04.html ) get through most of the hurdles of the process by adding Alpha's drive to Beta as follows:

Alpha's drive is installed at /dev/hdb in Beta's system. Beta's drive is /dev/hda.

Remaining hurdle:

**How to get grub-install/grub-probe/grub-mkconfig to ignore /dev/hda when looking for bootable kernel on /dev/hdb?**

After removing Alpha's drive into Alpha system and rebooting, system doesn't boot. There are no obvious error logs in Alpha's drive (after re-installing/mounting in Beta).  After a few cycles of this, I found:

grub-install's grub-probe detects Beta's kernel and associates the UUIDs from those (/dev/hda) instead of Alpha's installed ones at /dev/hdb

--even though user is chrooted into Alpha's drive ( /dev/sdb ) per instructions at help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/i386/apds04.html

I've run out of ideas on how to invoke grub-install/grub-probe/grub-mkconfig parameters to ignore /dev/hda.

For now, I will manually edit the grub file with bad referenced HD UUIDs: grub.cfg iirc. Let me know if there's a standard, less risky way to do this.

Comment: Look into `debootstrap`.

Comment: @fkraiem Excellent! Thank you. Just what I was looking for:  https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/i386/apds04.html

Comment: You could also copy the iso file to the beta drive and add a menuentry for it (for example using the 40_custom method). See this link, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/ISOBoot

Comment: Thank you @sudodus . AFAICT, the only useful changes to grub is to change boot defaults in a running OS --not to second HD-- since `sudo update-grub` is required after edit. However, I will add this to stack of tricks. Thank you again.

Comment: Hi again @fkraiem & sudodus. I'm stuck; Almost works. After removing 2nd hd into own system and rebooting, system doesn't boot. 

Finally figured out: grub-install's grub-probe detects primary system's HD and kernel and associates the UUIDs from those (/dev/hda) instead of /dev/hdb --even though I chrooted into /dev/sdb per instructions at https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/i386/apds04.html

How to get grub-install/grub-probe/grub-mkconfig to ignore /dev/hda when looking for bootable kernel?